# Integer solution to equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does $$b =a-23\sqrt 3 \sqrt a+432$$ have infinitely many integer solutions?

$a = 3$ gives one;

$a = 27$ gives one;

$a = 27\times 9$ gives one.

Comment: $a-23\sqrt 3\sqrt a+432$ with $a\in\mathbb Z$ is an integer iff $a=3n^2$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: Did you mean that minus sign in your first line is an equality sign $\,=\,$ ?

Comment: I have edited it\

Comment: you are not asking for solutions of $a-23\sqrt3\sqrt{a}+432=0$ I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = 3n^2,\;$ where $n$ is any integer (and hence $\,a = 3n^2$ must also be an integer.)

So
$$
\begin{align} 
b &= a-23\sqrt{3}\sqrt{a}+432 \\ \\
&= a -23\sqrt{3a}+ 432 \\ \\
 &= (3n^2)-23\sqrt{3^2n^2}+432\\&=3n^2-23\cdot3n+432\\ \\
\iff b &= 3(n^2 - 23n + 144)
\end{align}
$$
Hence, for $a = 3n^2,\;b = 3(n^2 - 23n + 144)$ is an also an integer for any given any integer $n$. Since $n$ can be any integer, and since there are infinitely many $n$, there are infinitely many solutions $(a, b)$, one solution per $n$, given by $$a = 3n^2;\;\;b = 3(n^2 - 23n + 144).$$

Answer (score 1):

For every $a=3k^2$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have

$$a-23\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3k^2}+432=3k^2-23\sqrt{3^2k^2}+432=3k^2-23\cdot3k+432$$ and this is obviously  an integer. As we have infinitely many integers k, there are infinitely many solutions